# Why is it possible to write the following term when using the summation solution to PCA?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, vectors, principal-component-analysis

I am going through PCA notes and I am stumped by the last line in the term expansion (see image below). How did we get $-2\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_{ji}x_j^Tv_i$ from the previous two middle terms?

EDIT:
In the note, we are trying to minimize the projection error of the j-th vector $x_j$ onto the subspace $W$. $W$ has the basis vectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_k$ which are all orthonormal. The goal is to figure out the optimal set of $\alpha$ and $v$ (as it is with PCA).

[image: Consider the following solution to the PCA problem using summation]

I understand that this might be something incredibly trivial but I can't figure it out. TIA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, the problem lies in the second to last line: $x_j\sum_{i=1}^k v_i^T\alpha_{ji}^T$ should be $(\sum_{i=1}^k v_i^T\alpha_{ji}^T)x_j$. And you don't need to transpose $\alpha_{ji}$ either, it's a scalar, so it's really $(\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_{ji}v_i^T)x_j$. And then, since $v_i^Tx_j$ is a scalar product, you can also write it as $x_j^Tv_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Jean-Claude's comment, I was able to figure it out. This is how the expression should be from the third line in the term expansion:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{N} \{ (x_j^T - \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i^T)(x_j - \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i) \}$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \{ x_j^Tx_j - x_j^T\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i - (\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i^T)x_j + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i^T\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i \}$$

$\because$ $v_i^Tx_j$ is a dot product and hence commutative, i.e. $v_i^Tx_j = x_j^Tv_i$. So, we can write the above term as:

$$=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \{ || x_j ||^2 - x_j^T\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i - \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}x_j^Tv_i + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}^2 \}$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \{ || x_j ||^2 - x_j^T\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i - x_j^T\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}^2 \}$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \{ || x_j ||^2 - 2x_j^T\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}v_i + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{ji}^2 \}$$

And the rest of the term expansion makes sense after that.